# How to create big datasets for test purposes?

Tags: c#, testing, charts, test-data

I need to test some charting classes. For these I want to create a big dataset of 1-2 million data! How can I create such big datasets?

thanks

Comment: What kind of data?  Random numbers?   DVD movie selection history weighting?  Heights?  What are the ranges?  Types?

Comment: sorry for my unspecific question. Dont know how to say, but i need datasets, that are changing all the time. In extreme case 2 million data the second. My charting class must plot this data in realtime. With this dataset i want to test existent charting classes. Dont know if its posible, but thats my mission :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

visual studio team system database edition has facilities to do this

[how to video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/cc501309.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit too open-ended, but in short you could create a program to generate random data. Basically for each data field, choose a data range (EG: 0 - 100, "true" / "false", etc). Then have your program populate each field with random data. Write that field to your dataset and repeat the process millions of times...

Answer (score 0):

copy any existing data and paste it millions of times.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(i = 1; i <= 2000000; i++) {
    insertRandomData();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything text based, you can use this as your seed, maybe just make it a string then split it into a string array and start combining random indexes of the array, and for numbers just use the random functionality. Here's your seed:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce scelerisque nulla congue felis interdum nec lobortis turpis blandit. Ut sagittis molestie lacinia. Phasellus iaculis justo vel ligula vestibulum pretium. Phasellus non iaculis nibh. Curabitur eu ipsum dignissim eros volutpat dignissim. Maecenas lobortis ultricies nisl, sit amet laoreet leo tristique eget. Donec ullamcorper, metus condimentum vehicula mollis, urna lorem tincidunt arcu, eget rutrum nisl enim sit amet enim. Aliquam ac mi tellus. Nullam vitae justo lacus, in posuere arcu. Aliquam fermentum lacus eu urna congue pellentesque. Nam malesuada tincidunt odio, eget adipiscing libero pulvinar sit amet. Ut risus dolor, condimentum non cursus ut, convallis vitae elit. Aliquam ultricies consequat nulla eget convallis. Maecenas eget sollicitudin neque. Etiam aliquam commodo sagittis. Morbi pellentesque metus ut eros euismod ullamcorper.

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of existing data sets, like the Stackoverflow user data.

Answer (score 0):

My project http://fluentetl.codeplex.com/ might help you with this.

You can easily use it to dump test data into your database and this is actually illustrated in the examples.

One example generates data through code. Another example joins 2 text files, a list of first names and a list of last names and inserts all possible combinations into a table. You can make your own loop of random data to save to your database.